# PostgreSQL IP address: Search the right result by inet data?

Tags: postgresql, inet

I have a problem on PostgreSQL when asking if a given IP address (`inet` type) search the right result in the database. I will provide step by step what I'm doing.

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
   ip inet,
   a character varying
);
INSERT INTO public.test (ip, a) VALUES
    ('1111:0000:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005', 'admin1'),
    ('1111:0001:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005', 'admin2'),
    ('1111:0011:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005', 'admin3'),
    ('1111:0111:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005', 'admin4'),
    ('1111:1111:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005', 'admin5');
```

Then I want search `ip` by `'1111:0'`, which should find the result

```
1111:0000:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005
1111:0001:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005
1111:0011:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005
1111:0111:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for some text representation of `inet` addresses (with f.ex. `LIKE`), you'll have a hard time; because `inet` output is canonized. F.ex.:

```
input                                   | output 
1111:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0005 | 1111::5/128
1111:0001:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005 | 1111:1:101:a:2:3:4:5/128
```

So, leading zeros are gone & and the largest block of only zeros are replaced with `::` (which is completely valid in IPv6).

But, if you want to find [`inet` addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html), which have 20 **leading bits** like `1111:0`, you can use [subnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).

For `1111:0`, you are really looking for the child (networks / ) hosts of `1111::/20` (with the [contains operator: `>>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html)):

```
select addr,
       inet '1111::/20' >> addr  "is within '1111::/20'"
from   (values (inet '1111:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0005'),
               (inet '1111:0001:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005'),
               (inet '1111:0011:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005'),
               (inet '1111:0111:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005'),
               (inet '1111:1111:0101:000A:0002:0003:0004:0005'),
               (inet '1111:F111:0101:0000:0000:0000:0000:0005')) v(addr)
```

Will produce:

```
addr                        | is within '1111::/20'
1111::5/128                 | t
1111:1:101:a:2:3:4:5/128    | t
1111:11:101:a:2:3:4:5/128   | t
1111:111:101:a:2:3:4:5/128  | t
1111:1111:101:a:2:3:4:5/128 | f
1111:f111:101::5/128        | f
```

http://rextester.com/ZFFFK28291

Comment: As you say,we can search the right ip which is head of the string(1111:0). If the ip is matching in the middle or end,this way can not solve this problem.

Comment: @ggg yes, you cannot search inside of `inet`, because its output is canonized. You could (in theory) search inside of the canonized form, but that wouldn't be the same (see the linked rextester examples).

Comment: I find a way that we could not only search the ip which is head of the string but also search which the string'1111:0' is in the middle or end.

Comment: @ggg without changing the column type to text/varchar? You can post it as an answer, if you feel, it satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from test where 
cast((ip)as varchar) like '%a000::%'
or cast((ip)as varchar) like '%a000:_:%'
or cast((ip)as varchar) like '%a000:__:%'
or cast((ip)as varchar) like '%a000:___:%
or cast((ip)as varchar) like '%a000:_____'
or cast((ip)as varchar) like '%a000:______'
or cast((ip)as varchar) like '%a000:_______'
```

Comment: But how does this help searching `1111:0` inside f.ex. `1111:1:101:a:2:3:4:5`? This will only work, when you search for only one block. And if that would be the case, you could use a single `LIKE` too.